# Can we import our custom extension into the Autodesk Forge demo site

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Some questions arise after I use this Autodesk forge.

1. Can we import our custom extension into the Autodesk Forge demo site ?
2. Can we import a model that we have, something like "human.fbx" overlay with the bim model from derivative as an extension?
3. I know there are several methods to create a custom model it is: overlay, impl and sceneBuilder. If we create a custom model as an extension, can I still interact with the viewer if I use a custom overlay.addMesh?.

Comment: 1. Which demo site?

Comment: @AugustoGoncalves Can we import the extension we made into this site https://forge-extensions.autodesk.io/ ? Or is there a demo site that Autodesk Forge provides so we can try out our custom extensions.

Answer (score 0):

1. The [forge-extensions](https://forge-extensions.autodesk.io/) is a showcase. As the [source code](https://github.com/autodesk-forge/forge-extensions) is available, you can fork it and add your own.
2. You can load multiple models
3. Please use the [supported approach](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/developers_guide/advanced_options/custom-geometry/):